# error: too few template-parameter-lists

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, gnu

Using the gnu compiler, I'm getting multiples of the error

```
error: too few template-parameter-lists
```

This confuses me since the intel compiler seems to handle this following code segment without so much as a warning:

```
// Template to retrieve traits of any MPI object
template <class T>
struct mpi_type_traits {
   typedef T element_type;
   typedef T* element_addr_type;
   static inline MPI_Datatype get_type(T&& val);
   static inline size_t get_size(T& val);
   static inline void* get_addr(T& val);
};

// Specialization of mpi_type_traits for primitive types
#define PRIMITIVE(Type, MpiType) \
        template<> \
        inline MPI_Datatype mpi_type_traits<Type>::get_type(Type&&) { return MpiType; } \
        inline size_t mpi_type_traits<Type>::get_size(Type&) { return 1; } \
        inline void* mpi_type_traits<Type>::get_addr(Type& val) { return &val; }
  PRIMITIVE(char, MPI::CHAR);
  PRIMITIVE(wchar_t, MPI::WCHAR);
  PRIMITIVE(short, MPI::SHORT);
  PRIMITIVE(int, MPI::INT);
  PRIMITIVE(long, MPI::LONG);
  PRIMITIVE(signed char, MPI::SIGNED_CHAR);
  PRIMITIVE(unsigned char, MPI::UNSIGNED_CHAR);
  PRIMITIVE(unsigned short, MPI::UNSIGNED_SHORT);
  PRIMITIVE(unsigned int, MPI::UNSIGNED);
  PRIMITIVE(unsigned long, MPI::UNSIGNED_LONG);
  PRIMITIVE(unsigned long long, MPI::UNSIGNED_LONG_LONG);
  PRIMITIVE(bool, MPI::BOOL);
  PRIMITIVE(std::complex<float>, MPI::COMPLEX);
  PRIMITIVE(std::complex<double>, MPI::DOUBLE_COMPLEX);
  PRIMITIVE(std::complex<long double>, MPI::LONG_DOUBLE_COMPLEX);

#undef PRIMITIVE
```

From reading around, this has something to do with the typename specification, but I can't quite pinpoint where it needs to be placed. It's clear the error arises from each PRIMITIVE.

Answer (score 2):

Ok figured it out. Needed to put template<> before each defined inline.

```
...
#define PRIMITIVE(Type, MpiType) \
    template<> \
    inline MPI_Datatype mpi_type_traits<Type>::get_type(Type&&) { return MpiType; } \
    template<> \
    inline size_t mpi_type_traits<Type>::get_size(Type&) { return 1; } \
    template<> \
    inline void* mpi_type_traits<Type>::get_addr(Type& val) { return &val; }
  PRIMITIVE(char, MPI::CHAR);
...
```